# ImportError: failed to find libmagic on Gitlab pipeline but working locally as mint

Tags: python, docker, gitlab

as the title says I'm able to run and test my app using python 3.8 with python-magic and libmagic locally as well as two mates pulling the same branch, but as soon as the pipeline on Gitlab starts testing will give:

```
    import magic
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/magic/__init__.py", line 209, in <module>
    libmagic = loader.load_lib()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/magic/loader.py", line 49, in load_lib
    raise ImportError('failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation')
ImportError: failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

All the questions related to "libmagic not found" are for python only not mentioning GitLab, I also use poetry for dependency management.

The pipeline will fail in this line:

- docker run --rm -e DOTENV=ci --add-host="postgres:$POSTGRES_IP" $REPOSITORY_URL test --no-input

The Dockerfile execution prior to this is successful and hasn't been changed. The only change in this branch has been related to libmagic and all was working before.

The gitlab version is 14.4.5

Docker installs the requirements this way:

```
RUN echo "====== System dependencies ======" && \
    apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache postgresql-libs && \
    apk add --no-cache postgresql-dev && \
    apk add --no-cache python3-dev py3-setuptools py3-virtualenv musl-dev gcc libffi-dev libxml2-dev \
                       libxml2 g++ libxslt-dev libuv make zlib-dev jpeg-dev git \
                       libressl-dev openssl libzmq zeromq-dev util-linux bash curl
```

Which I clearly can see the libmagic and python-magic dependencies being installed before the tests:

```
  • Installing libmagic (1.0)
  • Installing python-magic (0.4.27)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would look into whether your Docker image actually installs that library. Can you share the recipe used to create the image?

Comment: When you say it works locally, do you mean running the script locally on your machine, or running that docker command on your machine? If you're also using docker locally, are you using the exact same image locally and on GitLab?

Comment: Edited the post, thanks joanis. I'm going to try pulling the image and run it locally as you suggested. Yes, locally means on my machine.

Comment: Yes, I expected on your machine, but I guess I was not clear enough: are you running it locally using docker, or locally using a non-docker Python environment?

Comment: Plus, if you could turn your code into a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that would be really helpful. Right now, we cannot cut and paste what you gave us and try it on our own machine (or our own GitLab), so we cannot actually troubleshoot your problem.